# How can I avoid that JQuery reloads in Rails when clicking an option from a menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a menu with and it has the hover property. I would like that when click on the selected option it retains the background color (example: red ).

I notice that when clicking an option it reloads again the whole code and that's why the background colour stays just for some seconds until the whole page reloads. This is the code:

CSS code:

```
#menu {
    float:right;
    height: 100%;
    /*background-color: green;*/
}


#menu-icon {
    display: none;
    height: 40px;
    width:100px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 0 8px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    background: #fabb00;
    background: url("../images/menu_icon.png") center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #003d72;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width:150px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 0 16px 0 16px;
    text-align: center;
    }

#menu ul li.last {
    margin:0;
}

#menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:#fabb00;
}

/*#menu ul li.active {
    background: #fabb00;
}*/


#menu ul a {
    color: #003d72;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

In one partial I have:

```
<script >
  $(function () {
    $('ul li').on("click",function(){
            $(this).css('background','red');        
        });

});
  </script>
```

View of `b`

```
<h1>View of b</h1>
<%= render "partials/highlight" %>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
              <a href="#" id="menu-icon">Menu</a>
              <ul>
                <a href="http://localhost:3000/a"><li class="active">a</li></a>
                <a href="http://localhost:3000/b"><li>b</li></a>
                <a href="http://localhost:3000/c"><li>c</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="last">d</li></a>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

For example, when clicking `b` it calls `http://localhost:3000/b` and that is why the view for `b` it is again called and the partial (JQuery) as well and in this way it waits again for a click.

But how can I avoid that this JQuery code reloads when clicking any option?

Answer (score 0):

The structure itself is wrong. It has to be:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost:3000/a">a</li></a>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/b">b</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/c">c</a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="#">d</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `<ul>` cannot have any other element other than `<li>` as its descendant.